# Can depot storage be shared between my characters in the same server?

Tags: tibia

Is it possible to share depot storage between all characters in one account and the same server? Usually, I have to trade items by parcels, but maybe there is any solution to do it simpler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I'm aware of to share items among characters on the same server without using a parcel is by buying a house and invite all your characters.

Another way without using a parcel, nor a house, is to store your items in a hidden location (e.g. underneath a tree outside the city) and quickly change character to pick them up. It helps to put your target character at the spot before hand. However, this is risky and I don't recommend it. Someone might follow you, the server could suddenly disconnect or if it is really busy, you could be put in a queue for login.

TLDR; Use a parcel for non-premium, or buy a house on a premium account.

Comment: Ohh, those two tricks are unfortunately just workarounds. I usually sending items between my characters by parcels, but I thought that maybe there exist any way to turn shared depo on. Something like in Guild Wars. There all characters was one shared chest, and we could browse all our treasures, no matter on which character we are logged in.

Comment: @TravelerVihaan I understand what you mean, but that does not exist. I double checked the list of premium features and there is no such thing. Perhaps suggest it so CipSoft? :)